# Execute `insert into` command at specific position in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have following SQL query,

```sql
SELECT ID, post_title
  FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_type = 'post'
   AND post_status = 'publish'
    OR post_status = 'draft'
   AND ID NOT IN ($data)
   AND post_title NOT IN (1)
 ORDER BY ID DESC
 LIMIT 300
```

and I can execute a `SELECT` command at place of `$data` like that,

for `$data`:

```
1,2) AND (SELECT sleep(5)) AND `post_title` NOT IN (1
```

The query:

```
SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'draft' AND ID NOT IN (1,2) AND (SELECT sleep(5)) AND `post_title` NOT IN (1) AND post_title NOT IN (1) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 300
```

But, when I try an `INSERT INTO` command at same place, I'm getting following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near..
```

I think it's because of parentheses of `NOT IN` statement. So how can I implement `INSERT INTO` command in that SQL query? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the full SQL error message? You cut off the important part of the message.

Comment: What are you trying to insert? Please provide the complete INSERT statement.

Comment: You can't put an `INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE` query into the middle of another query like that, subqueries can only contain `SELECT` queries